# Open device camera for iPhone and Android in Unity3d

Tags: iphone, android-camera, unity-game-engine

I am working an application in which i need to open device camera in full view and i am making this app for both iOS and Android. So can any one tell me that how can i open full screen device camera in Unity for all devices Android and iPhone.
This will be great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: Why microsoft? I am using Unity in Mac OSX, and building app for iPhone and Android so why should i mention Microsoft.

Comment: No, there's a Microsoft product called Unity that's unrelated to the game engine/authoring tool. The correct tag for the engine is `unity3d`.

Comment: Right Calvin, I'll use Unity3d:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean you want to use the camera to take and save photographs, I'd recommend Prime31's iOS and Android plugins.  Unfortunately the Etcetera plugin is us$65 per platform, but I've used them both and they work great.

http://u3d.as/content/prime31/i-os-etcetera-plugin/2CU

http://u3d.as/content/prime31/android-etcetera-plugin/2CY

If you just want to show the camera's live output inside of your app's scene, you can create a plane and use a WebCamTexture to display the camera's live video output.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html

Answer (score 18):

After some more digging on Google and Official docs. I got solution which I am going to share with you , It help someone .. someday..

**1.Create New Project.**

**2.Select Main Camera in GameObject and change Transform via Inspector**

Position X= -90 Y=785 Z=0 Rotation X=90 Y=90 Z=0 Scale X=1 Y=1 Z=1

[image]

**3.Now go to GameObject — > Create Other — > Plane.**

**4.Select Main Camera in GameObject and**

*4.1 change Transform via Inspector*

Position X=0 Y=0 Z=0 Rotation X=0 Y=0 Z=0 Scale X=100 Y=100 Z=100
[image]

*4.2 change Tag=Player*

Now create a c# script with name “CameraController” and replace the code with below one

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
        public WebCamTexture mCamera = null;
        public GameObject plane;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
        {
                Debug.Log ("Script has been started");
                plane = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");

                mCamera = new WebCamTexture ();
                plane.renderer.material.mainTexture = mCamera;
                mCamera.Play ();

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update ()
        {

        }
}
```

**5.Finally save and Drag this Script file onto “Plane” GameObject**

Note - you may see preview rotated in Unity Game view but on RealDevice it works well. tested on iPhone5 and Android - Nexus 5.

Here is the snap shot how it comes if you change rotation angle to 180:
[image]

Comment: I am using your script to display camera. It is working perfectly. But how can I resize the plane in such a way that it resizes according to the device screen size? so that the plane can fit device height and width.

Comment: This isn't working in Unity 2019, The Device Camera is Starting but it not displaying anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is a toolkit available to open the device camera in unity for iOS and Android called CameraCaptureKit - (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673)

All the source is available and it has a plain and and simple plug'n'play demo as with Unity UI - it solves some of the obstacles involved with taking still images using the camera on your device.

Since the WebCamTexture is a generic solution to taking still images it doesn't enable sharpening of the images, the quality as well is more low-res on iOS since it uses a configuration for capturing real time video.

If you want to turn on flash / torch there you can do that with the toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great plugin named [Android native Camera](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/android-native-camera-116383) for open device camera and save the video or image inside the device. Currently, it works only android.